# API to get edits that transform string A to string B in java

Tags: java, string, nlp

What is the best API to get the edits required to transform string A to string B

```
A: This is a sentence
B: This was a sentences
```

Something like this
Edits:

1. {
   start: 5,
   end: 7,
   action: "replace"
   text: "was"
   }
2. {
   start: 18,
   action: "insert",
   text: "s"
   }

I know that I can do this on my own using Levenshtein distance algo, but I want to go with an industry-standard
If someone knows about any NLP/String Util or API that I can use in java, please help me out.

`Spacey errant` is an option, but that is for python. I am looking for something similar to that in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

Use [Diff Match Patch](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch) library. It offers the following features:

1. **Diff:** Compare two blocks of plain text and efficiently return a list of differences
2. **Match:** Given a search string, find its best fuzzy match in a block of plain text. Weighted for both accuracy and location.
3. **Patch:** Apply a list of patches onto plain text. Use best-effort to apply patch even when the underlying text doesn't match.

**Example** based on [this](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch/wiki/Language:-Java):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import name.fraser.neil.plaintext.diff_match_patch;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    diff_match_patch dmp = new diff_match_patch();
    LinkedList<diff_match_patch.Diff> diff = dmp.diff_main("This is a sentence", "This was a sentences");
    dmp.diff_cleanupSemantic(diff);
    System.out.println(diff);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Diff(EQUAL,"This "), Diff(DELETE,"i"), Diff(INSERT,"wa"), Diff(EQUAL,"s a sentence"), Diff(INSERT,"s")]
```

### Option 2

Use [Diff Utils](https://github.com/java-diff-utils/java-diff-utils) library, which is an actively maintained fork of [java-diff-utils from Google Code Archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-diff-utils/). Diff Utils allows comparison operations between texts: computing diffs, applying patches, etc.

**Example** (for more examples have a look [here](https://github.com/java-diff-utils/java-diff-utils/wiki/Examples)):

```
import com.github.difflib.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create a configured DiffRowGenerator
        DiffRowGenerator generator = DiffRowGenerator.create().showInlineDiffs(true).mergeOriginalRevised(true)
                .inlineDiffByWord(true).oldTag(f -> "~") // introduce markdown style for strikethrough
                .newTag(f -> "**") // introduce markdown style for bold
                .build();

        // compute the differences for two test texts.
        List<DiffRow> rows = generator.generateDiffRows(Arrays.asList("This is a sentence"),
                Arrays.asList("This was a sentences"));

        System.out.println(rows.get(0).getOldLine());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
This ~is~**was** a ~sentence~**sentences**
```

### Option 3

Create your own Diff utility, such as the one described [here](https://www.techiedelight.com/implement-diff-utility/). The code below is as given in the above source, and uses [Longest Common Subsequence (LCS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) - which is a variation of [Edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) ([Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)) - to solve this problem.

**Example:**

```
public class Main {
    // Function to display the differences between two strings
    public static void diff(String X, String Y, int m, int n, int[][] lookup) {
        // if the last character of `X` and `Y` matches
        if (m > 0 && n > 0 && X.charAt(m - 1) == Y.charAt(n - 1)) {
            diff(X, Y, m - 1, n - 1, lookup);
            System.out.print(" " + X.charAt(m - 1));
        }

        // if the current character of `Y` is not present in `X`
        else if (n > 0 && (m == 0 || lookup[m][n - 1] >= lookup[m - 1][n])) {
            diff(X, Y, m, n - 1, lookup);
            System.out.print(" +" + Y.charAt(n - 1));
        }

        // if the current character of `X` is not present in `Y`
        else if (m > 0 && (n == 0 || lookup[m][n - 1] < lookup[m - 1][n])) {
            diff(X, Y, m - 1, n, lookup);
            System.out.print(" -" + X.charAt(m - 1));
        }
    }

    // Function to fill the lookup table by finding the length of LCS
    // of substring X[0…m-1] and Y[0…n-1]
    public static int[][] findLCS(String X, String Y, int m, int n) {
        // lookup[i][j] stores the length of LCS of substring X[0…i-1] and Y[0…j-1]
        int[][] lookup = new int[X.length() + 1][Y.length() + 1];

        // first column of the lookup table will be all 0
        for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
            lookup[i][0] = 0;
        }

        // first row of the lookup table will be all 0
        for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            lookup[0][j] = 0;
        }

        // fill the lookup table in a bottom-up manner
        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                // if current character of `X` and `Y` matches
                if (X.charAt(i - 1) == Y.charAt(j - 1)) {
                    lookup[i][j] = lookup[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
                }
                // otherwise, if the current character of `X` and `Y` don't match
                else {
                    lookup[i][j] = Integer.max(lookup[i - 1][j], lookup[i][j - 1]);
                }
            }
        }

        return lookup;
    }

    // Implement diff utility in Java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String X = "This is a sentence";
        String Y = "This was a sentences";

        // lookup[i][j] stores the length of LCS of substring X[0…i-1] and Y[0…j-1]
        int[][] lookup = findLCS(X, Y, X.length(), Y.length());

        // find the difference
        diff(X, Y, X.length(), Y.length(), lookup);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 T h i s   -i +w +a s   a   s e n t e n c e +s
```